# pycharm - when should I use find in path (cmd-shift-f) and when should I use search everywhere (double shift)?

Tags: pycharm

When should I use find in path `cmd-shift-f` and when should I use search everywhere `double shift`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `cmd-shift-f` if you want to search for a `specific word` in overall project
on the other hand
You should use `double shift` if you want to search for a `specific file` in overall project